# Copying cell with hyperlink changes url when pasting

Tags: excel, hyperlink

**Background:**

I have a tracking spreadsheet that I input links to a repository (SharePoint) for persons to follow/find information.  All links can be followed from this sheet by clicking on the cell.  I have not seen any of the links exceed 255 characters (typically about 100 characters).

This is the sole spreadsheet I have the issue with, where it is maintained on SharePoint/Teams.  In attempting to trouble shoot based on storage location, I made a local copy and attempted to copy/paste and the issue was resolved.

The choice to be on SharePoint/Teams is business necessity to reach a large audience; even the use of a network drive is being ruled out as an option.

---

**Issue:**

When I copy a cell from this tracking spreadsheet, pasting it into either another spreadsheet, into an Outlook email, etc., the link is changed.

Was:  https://company.sharepoint.com/a/b/c/finalLocation

Becomes:  ../../../../a/b/c/finalLocation

Note that the dot-dot-slash is four times prior to `a` in all cases.

---

**Questions:**

*Why* does this happen when using the spreadsheet loaded from Teams/SharePoint and *how* might I fix this that doesn't involve finding another location storage location?

Comment: It looks like the absolut filepath is changed to a relative filepath. "../" means one folder up. Maybe changing the Web options will help? https://zditect.com/blog/58750452.html

Comment: @WeAreOne I appreciate the response, though can say that this did not resolve the issue.  I tested after in both scenarios that Copying from the Excel file on Teams still truncates and if I save the same file locally (without closing after doing the Teams-sheet copy/paste into Outlook) then copy/paste into Outlook and the links remain un-truncated.  I feel this is tied to Teams/SharePoint, but cannot fathom why/how.